# Application to application big data transfer - HBase service in the middle

Tags: java, rest, sockets, hbase, rpc

I have a table in HBase which stores several billions of rows. There is a bit of "intelligence" in the row key design and the way the data is read and write. For example: the row keys are prefixed with a salt, the Reads use a custom HBase filter, there is a bit of multi-threading to perform several Scans in parallel...

Several applications will consume this data. I see several options:

1. Implement the piece of "intelligence" in each client application and make those client applications directly use the HBase API to access the data. Duplicating the intelligence in several client applications looks like a bad thing as it will be hard to maintain if the bit of intelligence as to change.
2. Implement a library to "encapsulate" this intelligence and make the client applications use this library. Same, if the intelligence changes, how to be sure that all the client applications use the last version of the library
3. Implement this intelligence in a (micro) service. All the client applications will access HBase data through this service. To me, this is the best solution. If the intelligence changes, I just have to change the code in this service and it's okay (as far as the interface with the client applications is not impacted of course).

So I would like to go with this third option. However, the amount of data that could be read in a single call by client application could involve millions of records. How do I make the client applications and the service communicate efficiently? I have the feeling that REST Services are for small amounts of data. I think I need a kind of streaming strategy where the service send data to the client application while it is extracting it from HBase. I think I should not extract the whole dataset in the service, then send it to the client. It would lead to out of memory exceptions.

My strategy so far is to be "low level". I use Java socket. The service has a ServerSocket waiting for client socket. When client application wants to read, a socket communication is created. Client app sends search criteria to the service through the socket communication. Then the service retrieves data matching search criteria. The service writes data in the socket's output stream (using DataOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream) on the fly while it receives data from HBase (extracted with the classical HBase API). On the other side, the client application reads the socket input stream and decode the data. To not bother client application code with this low-level socket handling, I created a library to "encapsulate" that.

What do you think? Is it the correct approach? Is it too "low level"? Is there less "low level" approach that you could advise to transfer huge amounts of data from app to app while keeping good performance (REST, RMI, RPC, ...)?

Comment: @ Comencau you shouldn't move data in big data concept.

Comment: @vahid Thank you. It really helps.

Comment: why you want define middle ware between client and hbase. why client can't run for example mapreduce directly on hbase. ( if is slow he/she can optimize mapreduce for that) .

Comment: how about writing data in hdfs and send location path to second app and second app process data in hdfs.